# How do I revert sys.stdout.close()?

Tags: python

In the interactive console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout
<open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0xb7810078>
>>> sys.stdout.close()
>>> sys.stdout # confirming that it's closed
(...) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Attempting to revert:

```
>>> sys.stdout.open()
(...) AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'open'
>>> sys.stdout.write('foo')
(...) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I agree that it's a frivolous question, but I'm curious how sys.stdout.close() can be reverted in Python (without restarting the interactive console, of course) and why sys.stdout.open() does not make sense.

Answer (score 10):

Okay, so I hope you are on a unix system...

Basically sys.stdout is just a variable containing any writable object.

So we can do magic like

```
sys.stdout = open("file", "w")
```

and now we can write to that file as if it was stdout.

Knowing unix is just one big box of files. Unix is kind enough to give us `/dev/stdout`

So to re-open stdout its simple

```
sys.stdout = open("/dev/stdout", "w")
```

Job done, you now have a new stdout opened up.

Edit

```
>>> os.fstat(1)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=8592, st_ino=7, st_dev=11L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_size=0, st_atime=1374230552, st_mtime=1374230552, st_ctime=1374230434)
>>> sys.stdout.close()
>>> sys.stdout = open("/dev/stdout", "w")
>>> sys.stdout.fileno()
3
>>> os.fstat(3)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=8592, st_ino=7, st_dev=11L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_size=0, st_atime=1374230576, st_mtime=1374230576, st_ctime=1374230434)
>>> os.fstat(1)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=8592, st_ino=7, st_dev=11L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_size=0, st_atime=1374230576, st_mtime=1374230576, st_ctime=1374230434)
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

In your case, you can get the `sys.stdout` back by `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(1, 'w', 0)`.

But, in truth, you do not close the `sys.stdout` really. If you want to close it completely, you have to use `os.close(sys.stdout.fileno())`. You can read [Why doesn’t closing sys.stdout (stdin, stderr) really close it?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#why-doesn-t-closing-sys-stdout-stdin-stderr-really-close-it) for why. In this case, I don't know how to reopen it. The above method or even `open('/dev/stdout', 'w')` have failed on my Linux.

Comment: why  0 in `os.fdopen(1, 'w', 0)`? Also, the answer would probably be more helpfull with an explanation to what `1` and `w` are. I'm guessing '1' for `stdout` and `w` for a writable file handle

Answer (score 0):

sys.stdout.open() doesn't make any sense because open takes a filename and mode as parameters and a closed stream object doesn't have an open method.

The main answer is ***Don't Close It In The First Place!***

Answer (score 0):

The reason why sys.stdout.open() does not make sense whereas sys.stdout.close() does (despite the apparent symmetry), is that .open() and .close() apply to the stream/file, to which sys.stdout is just a pointer (and sys.stdout doesn't point to any stream/file once the latter is closed).