# How to obtain the file descriptor of the current terminal in python?

Tags: python, stdout, file-descriptor, python-multiprocessing

`sys.__stdout__.fileno()` returns the file descriptor of the terminal window that this python terminal session begins in.

But if some bootstrap process closes this file or the file never existed to begin with, how would I create a new fd for the current terminal window so I can do something like:

```
sys.__stdout__ = os.fdopen(new_fd, 'w')
sys.__stdout__.write('hi\r\n')
'hi'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743052/how-do-i-revert-sys-stdout-close looks like what you want

Comment: I'm on windows unfortunately so do not have access to /dev/tty etc

Comment: try `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(1, 'w', 0)`

Comment: doesn't work when the file the fd references has already been closed/never opened, as is the case in certain Win32GUI cases.